# How to permute a matrix column per column [VHDL]

Tags: matrix, vhdl, permutation, xilinx

i have a little matrix (5,8) and i want permute bits of each column on my matrix depend on the vector **col** <= (2,4,0,1,3); which comport each new place for the correspond iteration. Each column's bits will take the new positions given by **col** vector.

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
 use ieee.numeric_std.all;
 use IEEE.math_real.all;
 use IEEE.math_complex.all;
 USE IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;
 use IEEE.std_logic_arith.ALL;

entity permutation is
 port(
 clk : in std_logic;
 rst : in std_logic;
 datain: in std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
 dataout : out std_logic_vector(39 downto 0)
  );
 end permutation;

  architecture Behavioral of permutation is
  signal datain : std_logic_vector(39 downto 0) := "1011011101100110011001010110011001100110";
  signal temp: std_logic_vector(39 downto 0);
  type matrix is array(0 to 4,0 to 7) of std_logic;
  type table5 is array (0 to 4) of integer;
  signal mat1, matC: matrix;
  signal col: table5;
  signal pp:integer;
   signal j1,j2,i1,jx,ix,i2,i3,i4,per1,per2,ux: integer range 0 to 39;
  begin

  process(clk,rst)
  begin 

  if rst='1' then
  mat1<=(others=>(others=>'0'));
  elsif clk'event and clk='1' then      
      for j1 in 0 to 7 loop   --convert the vector datain to matrix mat1(5,8)
     for i1 in 0 to 4 loop 
     mat1(i1,j1)<=datain(j2);
      j2<=j2+1;
      end loop; 
      end loop; 
      end if;
  end process;

  process(clk, mat1)
  begin
  col<=(2,4,0,1,3); -- new places for each bit correspond to each iteration 
   -- permutation per column
  if (rising_edge(clk)) then    
  for ix in 0 to 4 loop
  for jx in 0 to 7 loop
     pp<=col(ux);
     if(jx = pp) then
    matC(per1,per2)<=mat1(ix,jx); --matC is the new matrix after permutation of each comumn's bits on mat1
   ux<=ux+1;
   per1 <= per1+1; 
     end if; 
     end loop; 
     per2 <= per2+1; 
     end loop;
    end if;

  --display      
 if(falling_edge(clk))then        
    for i3 in 0 to 7 loop
 for i2 in 0 to 4 loop  
temp(i4) <= matC(i2,i3);
i4<=i4+1;
end loop; 
end loop;   
end if;

end process;
dataout<=temp;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Do you have a specific [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)? **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:** 1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. *Your code example doesn't analyze (compile).*

Comment: Yes my problem that my code doesn't analyze and i want someone help me to correct it. i m trying to permute each column's bits respecting to the given position in the vector COL. i hope it's clear more now. Thank you

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting? Please include it in the question.